# D Gray Man's 14th Melody song is in what episodes?

Tags: theme-song, d-gray-man

Melody or Joined Hands Sealed with a Kiss song appears in the 93rd episode. But if I recall this song or part of it (or atleast the music) appears before episode 93. I want to know what episode is that.